# Mail app segue (open-with) with incorrect navigation bar colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uidocumentinteraction

I am currently attempting to open up the iOS mail all to create a draft with an attachment generated from my app. Here is a code snippet:

```
NSURL *fileLocation = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.site.dataFileLoc];
    if(fileLocation) {
        self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileLocation];
        [self.documentController setDelegate:self];
        [self.documentController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

However, what I am finding is that the navigation bar colours are completely off. In the AppDelegate, I am currently using these lines to set the global navigation bar appearance:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarBackground"] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIViewController class], nil] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shadow"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
```

Unfortunately, the title of the mail view controller that appears is still black, despite my attempt to set the bar style to black (which should make the title white in return) and blue bar buttons. It does, however, seem to work fine for the "presentPreviewAnimated" view controller. How can I make the navigation bar of the mail view controller consistent?

[image: Nav bar appearance]

Answer (score 0):

Are there any nibs associated??

I usually try to avoid the desired level of UI customization (navigation bar styles, colors, custom background w/image) because drawing UI at runtime (unless dynamically required) generally gets me in trouble...

Why not mock it up in a .nib file and make use of the fancy-dance-y tools in Xcode?? Can be therapeutic to quickly obtain the desired grain of detail without having to hit run...